# Output of a Hadoop Mapreduce to local disk or STDOUT

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it compulsory to write the output of a hadoop map reduce program to HDFS. Can we write it to local disk or display it on stdout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom class that extends TextOutputFormat and override getRecordWriter() method. Within that, you can write the output to a local fs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is must to have files in hadoop directory, it depends on how you are running the MapReduce job. When I run my mapreduce program from eclipse it runs in "Standalone" mode and it creates a folder in my personal file system.

Another mode of operation for mapreduce is "distributed" mode.

My map reduces driver class lines, where I mention output and input path.

```
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("src/demo/fulldictionary.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("output"));
```

Comment: What happens when you run in distributed mode ?

Comment: Hi Moiz - please check http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/single_node_setup.html#Local for more details about modes of operations.